# cannot import name 'uix_path' from 'kivymd'

Tags: python, kivymd

i got this answer     ( from kivymd import uix_path
ImportError: cannot import name 'uix_path' from 'kivymd')

```
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatIconButton, MDFillRoundFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.toolbar.toolbar import MDTopAppBar


class Raal(MDApp):
    def biuld(self):
        self.title = "Raal"
        self.icon = "logo.png"
        
        screen = MDScreenManager()

        
        self.toolbar = MDTopAppBar( title = " Raal Eat ")
        self.toolbar.pos_hint = {"top" : 1}
        screen.add_widget(self.toolbar)

        return screen

if __name__=="__main__" :
    Raal().run()
```

Comment: `from kivymd import uix_path ` That code does not appear anywhere in the code you posted...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will help someone. I had the same issue the code that previously worked perfectly. The only thing that helped me was reinstalling `kivymd`.